# Hagamos [if] sinónimo de [condiciones]

Tags: característica-nueva, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

[if](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if) tiene 114 preguntas etiquetadas y se define como:

> Sentencia condicional if en varios lenguajes de programación.

[condiciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condiciones) tiene 69 pregunta y se explica mucho mejor:

> En programación, una sentencia condicional (también llamada expresión condicional o simplemente condicional) es una estructura en el lenguaje de programación que ejecutará computaciones/acciones diferentes dependiendo del resultado de una condición booleana.

Hay [11 preguntas con ambas etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condiciones+if).

Parece bastante claro que ambas se refieren a lo mismo y mantenerlas en paralelo no ayuda. Por ello, creo útil juntarlas en una sola y por eso hace tiempo propuse que [if](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if) sea sinónima de [condiciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condiciones) (por eso de utilizar la versión en castellano). Lo propuse en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/condiciones/synonyms y no lleva ningún voto, probablemente porque 1) casi nadie utiliza esta parte del sitio para votar sinónimos y 2) muy poca gente puede votar favorablemente (casi nadie supera la reputación de 5 en la etiqueta).

Así pues, ¿podríamos juntar ambas etiquetas?

---

Además, [formato-condicional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formato-condicional), con apenas 6 preguntas, seguramente debería seguir el mismo camino, si bien veo que se le definió un uso muy concreto:

> Usar para preguntas sobre la característica de "formato condicional" que tienen aplicaciones de hoja de cálculo y bases de datos como Excel, Hoja de Cálculo de Google, Calc, Microsoft Access, Microsoft Visio, entre otros.

Si bien estoy de acuerdo en la definicion, si es tan específico de MS se podría renombrar para hacerlo más evidente, pues actualmente se usa como sinónimo de [condiciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condiciones) en al menos dos casos ([1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/178910/83), [2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/184763/83)), probablemente porque su nombre es bastante *apetecible* para preguntar sobre cómo gestionar condiciones en un algoritmo. Y de hecho sería un nombre incluso mejor que *condiciones*.

Comment: Espero un día más y le doy candela

Comment: yo quemaria las dos etiquetas.. no entiendo que tipo de pregunta puede tener esta etiqueta como valida.

Comment: uh, hice bien en esperar, hay opiniones al respecto ^^

Comment: @gbianchi las etiquetas de cualquier lenguaje que use un [IF] y el OP no sepa implementarlo correctamente en conjunto con otros operadores lógicos.

Answer (score 1):

No estoy del todo convencido con que la wiki de [condiciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condiciones) sea correcto porque ciertos espacios de documentación se refiere a **condición** como una expresión mientras que una **expresión** es diferente de una **sentencia**.

En el caso de la documentación en MDN si hay definiciones de **sentencia** pero no de **condición** ni de **expresión**, sin embargo, me parece que es claro que se distingue que una sentencia es "una" línea de código completa mientras que una condición es una expresión y a su vez esta es una combinación de constantes, variables, funciones y operadores que devuelven un valor.

Por ejemplo, en la página de [if..else](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/if...else) se dice que if es una sentencia que usa una condición la cual es una expresión

En lo que respecta a los dos casos referidos que usan [formato-condicional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formato-condicional) me parece que los OPs escribieron en la caja de etiquetas algo que podría haber sido  `condicional` y la única opción que se les mostró fue [formato-condicional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formato-condicional). Esto tiene sentido en la pregunta que habla de "condicionales ternarios", la otra sólo el OP sabrá que hizo.

Por lo anterior no estoy para nada convencido de hacer [if](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if) sinónimo de [condiciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condiciones) así como tampoco estoy convencido de [formato-condicional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formato-condicional) sea sinónimo de [condiciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condiciones).

---

## JavaScript

De [Sentencias](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias):

> Las aplicaciones JavaScript se componen de sentencias con una sintaxis propia. Una sentencia puede estar formada por múltiples líneas. Puede haber varias sentencias en una sola línea si separamos cada una de las sentencias por un punto y coma. No es una palabra clave, sino un grupo de palabras clave.

## Glosario

De [Sentencias](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Sentencias)

> En un lenguaje de programación, una **sentencia** es una línea de código al mando de una tarea Cada programa consiste en una secuencia de sentencias.

Comment: Ajá, buen punto. Digamos que "if" y "condiciones" están en mundos parecidos, pero no son lo mismo. ¿Y si definiéramos una taxonomía alrededor de la etiqueta madre [formato-condicional], que incluyera [if], [else], [if-else], [if-elif-else]?

Comment: @fedorqui: Opino que [tag:formato-condicional] no sería apropiado como "etiqueta madre" de [tag:condiciones] pues para mí formato se refiere a forma, diseño, color, etc. de documentos no a sentencias ni a sintaxis de programación aunque podría referirse al estilo de código entendiendo por ello el uso de espacios, tabuladores, resaltado de palabras clave, etc. que tengan como "motivación" la estética, facilidad de lectura no tanto reglas sintácticas como sería el orden de las palabras clave, operadores y otros símbolos.

Comment: Pensé proponer la creación de [tag:sentencias-condicionales] como "etiqueta madre" de [tag:if] y [tag:while], esta última tiene 95 preguntas, y no tiene ni orientación de uso ni wiki, sin embargo, al pensarlo un poco más me surge la duda pues [tag:while] también tendría [tag:bucles] como "etiquetas madre" . Me pregunto si queremos eso.

Comment: Recién revisé los casos referidos que usan [tag:formato-condicional]. Edité mi respuesta para agregar un comentario sobre estas.

Comment: ¿Y si englobamos todas en una que sea [estructuras-de-control](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estructuras_de_control)?

Comment: @KacosPro [tag:if] y [tag:while], así como también [tag:bucles], bien podrían ser sinónimos de [tag:estructuras-de-control] (creo que habrá que crear primero esta etiqueta) pero [tag:formato-condicional] considero que debe quedar independiente. Por otro lado, en relación a [tag:condiciones] hay que tener presente también a [tag:operador-ternario].

Comment: Quizás en lugar de sinónimos podría ser la "etiqueta madre". Sugiero abrir una nueva discusión al respecto.

Comment: secundo la opinión de @Rubén deberíamos proponer un diagrama de flujo de etiquetas madres... y anclarlo en algún sitio para los que quieran verificar si están usando correctamente las etiquetas...